# How to pass docs from template to parser class?

Tags: odoo

how to pass the docs from template of a report to parser class so that I can modify the report

```
class purchase_report(report_sxw.rml_parse):
    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
        super(purchase_report, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
        self.localcontext.update({
            'time': time,
            'get_purchase': self.get_purchase,
            })

     def get_purchase(self):
        cr = self.cr
        uid = self.uid
        purchase_obj=self.pool.get('purchase.order')
        ids = purchase_obj.search(cr, uid, [])
        records = purchase_obj.browse(cr, uid, ids)
        print "yes"
        return record
```

my template

```
<template id="report_wizard">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
        <t t-call="report.external_layout">
        <div class="page">
            <div class="oe_structure" />
                  <td>
                      <strong>Purchase Order:
                      <t t-set="records" t-value="get_purchase()"/>
                      <table>
                          <thead>
                              <th>Reference</th>
                              <th>Order Date</th>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                              <tr t-foreach="records" t-as="record">
                                  <tr t-if = "record.partner_id.name == doc.customer.name">
                                      <td><span t-esc="record.name"/> </td>
                                      <td><span t-esc="record.date_order"/></td>
                                  </tr>
                          </tr>
                          </tbody>
                      </table>
                  </strong>
                  </td>
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

and now I have my wizard in this template as docs. I need that docs in my above mentioned parser class.
how to get it?

Comment: need a function which should be called at template.  issue solved for me

Answer (score 2):

On template pass `docs`  on function call:

```
 <t t-set="records" t-value="get_purchase(doc)"/>
```

And catch that on your functions :

def get_purchase(self, docs):

This will let you have record being printed. Moreover docs is default is key in your `self.localcontext` so you can always grab docs key from localcontext.

Bests,